# other way to add item to List<>

Tags: c#, list, lambda

In my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511240/listelement-initialization-fires-process-is-terminated-due-to-stackoverflowexc) You can see code of my *arr* structure and *PriorityQueue* collection. I normally add items to this collection like that:

```
arr.PriorityQueue.Add(new element((value(item, endPoint) + value(startPoint, item)),item));
```

I am curious that is other way to do this (add element(which is struct) object to List) ? In lambda way for example ? I just eager for knowledge  :)

Comment: Other *question*, not "other ask". *Ask* is only a verb, and cannot be used as a noun, despite the fact that *question* can be used as noun and a verb. English can be tricky... I'm sure I'd sound like an idiot in your native language :)

Comment: @Mike - for some people, learning English is a big ask!

Comment: Haha, don't confuse him! I'm not faulting him for it, just offering a correction. Spend some time on http://livemocha.com and you can't help but offer tips :)

Comment: Yeah, I just find that "a big ask" saying amusing (it's becoming increasingly common in the UK).

Comment: Interesting. Never heard it here in the US. Armchair google etymology says it originated in Australia! http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/04/adjective-ask.html

Comment: @Mike - I understand every word You write,I have problems only with write in English. Every day I read articles, blogs etc in English, but I write more in Polish unfortunately :/

Comment: @Netmajor - you're a better man than I am. (I am assuming you are male)

Comment: First off, your structures should not be structures at all, they should be classes. Structures that contain reference types is mostly pointless, and mutable structures are tricky to use.

Comment: @Guffa - thanks for advice, I try to use it in next project, or maybe i change this one ;)
@Mike - Yes, I'm male :P About what You based?(I write is good?);)

Comment: @Guffa - I create from structures classes and really it looks better for me ,Tnx!

Comment: @netmajor: No, this is just a male-heavy website!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  arrays arr = new arrays();
        arr.PriorityQueue = new List<element>(
            new [] { 
                new element {node = 1, priority =2 }, 
                new element { node = 2, priority = 10}
                //..
                //..
            });


        arrays arr2 = new arrays();
        arr2.PriorityQueue = new List<element>(
            arr.PriorityQueue
            );


        arrays arr3 = new arrays();
        arr3.PriorityQueue = new List<element>(arr2.PriorityQueue.FindAll(z => (1 == 1)));


        arrays arr4 = new arrays();
        arr4.PriorityQueue = new List<element>(arr3.PriorityQueue.ToArray());
```

Comment: I need a while for see this arrays dependences :P Some far-fetched examples.. but this I want. Thank You ;)

Answer (score 4):

To add a new object to a list, you need to instantiate it.

The way you are doing it is correct, there is not lambda syntax or other [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for this operation.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(VS.85).aspx). It accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can pass it any collection of `T`, including arrays or the results of Linq expressions:

```
importantItems.AddRange(allItems.Where(item => item.IsImportant));
```

Comment: Based on Your code... maybe I can do something like that : 
arr.PriorityQueue.Add(new element(key,value)(key=>((value(item, endPoint) + value(startPoint, item))),value=>item));

I am sure that I see something like that ! sic!;/

Comment: Are you thinking of object initializer syntax? e.g. `new element { key = x, value = y }`